# ORDER BY FIELD , given field order comes at last

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am having table "business" as bellow

[image]

I want to fetch the record order by type in custom order. So I wrote the query like
SELECT * FROM `business` 
        ORDER BY FIELD (type, 'type3', 'type2', 'type10')

but what happen is other types comes up in order and the given order becomes at last. The given order should be at top and then other records. Above query returns the result as bellow.
[image]

How to bring the type3, type2 and type10 at top in order.

Answer (score 1):

So that will be:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  business 
ORDER BY 
  `type` IN ('type3', 'type2', 'type10'),
  FIELD (`type`, 'type3', 'type2', 'type10')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE `type`
    WHEN 'type3' THEN 1
    WHEN 'type2' THEN 2
    WHEN 'type10' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the selective data in top of the result set using `field` function you have to use either `ASC` or `DESC` on these set of values. Else the default result will be returned. Yours is an example of it.

You can try with

```
ORDER BY FIELD (type, 'type3', 'type2', 'type10') DESC
```

to see the results as

```
type10
type2
type3
```

> *How to bring the type3, type2 and type10 at top in order*

Using `ASC` will result

```
type3
type2
type10
```

The input order of data to the function `Field` is the *priority* for display when used with `ASC` or `DESC`. Else the result would be default.

> *These fields I do not have given in query*

They sure will be in resultset unless you specify a `WHERE` condition. `FIELD` function is not an alias to `WHERE` clause.

***Refer to***:

- [Ordering by specific field values with MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)
- [MySQL: Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sorting-rows.html)